# How do you talk to custom DBUS object with Python?

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I have some custom applications that is using dbus to communicate...

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
obj = bus.get_object(
    "org.freedesktop.DBus",
    "/org/freedesktop/DBus"
)

def listNames(names):
    for name in names:
        print "%s" % name

listNames(obj.ListNames());
```

I'm getting something like this coming back, example:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus
:1.7
test.helloworld
test.blahblah
test.customapp
```

At this point how do I listen or talk to those `test.*` applications? In fact, any application returned by the DBus's `get_object`.

I read
https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html but not helping for what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Perhaps this answer can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148109/how-to-use-the-existing-services-in-dbus

Answer (score 0):

dbus-python is deprecated, pydbus is the modern Python binding for DBus. With pydbus:

To get a proxy object:

```
from pydbus import SystemBus
bus = SystemBus()
dev = bus.get('org.freedesktop.NetworkManager', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0')
```

To see the API of a specific proxy object:

```
help(dev)
```

To call a method:

```
dev.Disconnect()
```

To read a property:

```
print(dev.Autoconnect)
```

To set a property:

```
dev.Autoconnect = True
```

To subscribe to a signal:

```
dev.StateChanged.connect(print)
loop.run()
```

More information: https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst

Disclaimer: I'm the author of pydbus.